# How to sum progress values of two seekbars in text view?

Tags: java, android

I have written this code. I want to sum the progress values of two seekbars in a text view. I have tried several time but it doesn't work. I want to some both values in a variable. Where I can use the variable in percentage etc.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  seekBar1=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.moveOnSeekBar1);    seekBar2=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.moveOnSeekBar2);    screenView1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.screenView1);   screenView2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.screenView2);   screenViewTotal=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.screenViewTotal);
    final int total;
    total=progress1Value+progress2Value;
    seekBar1.setMax(20);    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress1, boolean p3)
            {   screenView1.setText(Integer.toString(progress1));
                progress1Value=progress1;   screenViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        });
    seekBar2.setMax(20);    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress2, boolean p3)
            {   screenView2.setText(Integer.toString(progress2));
                progress1Value=progress2;   screenViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1)
            {
            }
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar p1)
            {
                // TODO: Implement this method
            }
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have taken your code and modified it. Create two fields, `progress1` and `progress2`. Then as the user interacts with the seekbars, update the correct value. Then call `updateTotal()`, which will calculate your total so you can use it to display the information.

```
private int progress1 = 0;
private int progress2 = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...
    seekBar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress1, boolean p3) {   
                this.progress1 = progress1;
                updateTotal();
            }
            // ...
        });

    // ...
    seekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar p1, int progress2, boolean p3) {   
                this.progress2 = progress2;
                updateTotal();
            }

            // ...
        });
}

private void updateTotal() {
    int total = progress1 + progress2;
    screenViewTotal.setText(String.valueOf(total));

    // do whatever else you want with the total.
}
```

Comment: Bro I have tried it but do not work. Can you please send me full code. I am a beginner.

Comment: All I did was add in a few lines of code, and another function. What didn't work? The `// ...` is just me removing your existing code to shorten the example.

Comment: this.progress1 = progress1;
In this line shown progress1 error and same with progress2

Comment: What is the error? Have you defined `progress1` above, as I did?